# Editing cell entries in a variable in a data frame inside a list of data frames

Tags: list, r, data-manipulation, data-management

Define:

```
> dats <- list( df1 = data.frame(a=sample(1:3), b = as.factor(rep("325.049072M",3))),
+       df2 = data.frame(a=sample(1:3), b = as.factor(rep("325.049072M",3))))
> dats
$df1
  a           b
1 3 325.049072M
2 2 325.049072M
3 1 325.049072M

$df2
  a           b
1 2 325.049072M
2 1 325.049072M
3 3 325.049072M
```

I want to remove the M character from column b in each data frame.

In a simple framework:

```
> t<-c("325.049072M","325.049072M")
> t
[1] "325.049072M" "325.049072M"
> t <- substr(t, 1, nchar(t)-1)
> t
[1] "325.049072" "325.049072"
```

But in a nested one, how to proceed?  Here is one sorry attempt:

```
> dats <- list( df1 = data.frame(a=sample(1:3), b = as.factor(rep("325.049072M",3))),
+       df2 = data.frame(a=sample(1:3), b = as.factor(rep("325.049072M",3))))
> dats
$df1
  a           b
1 3 325.049072M
2 1 325.049072M
3 2 325.049072M

$df2
  a           b
1 2 325.049072M
2 3 325.049072M
3 1 325.049072M

> for(i in seq(along=dats)) {
+   dats[[i]]["b"] <- 
+           substr(dats[[i]]["b"], 1, nchar(dats[[i]]["b"])-1)
+ }
> dats
$df1
  a         b
1 3 c(1, 1, 1
2 1 c(1, 1, 1
3 2 c(1, 1, 1

$df2
  a         b
1 2 c(1, 1, 1
2 3 c(1, 1, 1
3 1 c(1, 1, 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `lapply` (and some coercion):

```
stripM <- function(x){
x$b <- substr(as.character(x$b),1,nchar(as.character(x$b))-1)
x
}
lapply(dats,FUN=stripM)
```

If you need that variable as a factor, you can include a line in `stripM` that converts is back to a factor, something like `x$b <- as.factor(x$b)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `gsub` instead of `substr` - something like this:

```
lapply(<data.frame or list>, function(x) as.numeric(gsub("M$", "", x)))
```

of course, you need to figure out how are you going to recurse into list elements etc. but I guess you get the picture...

Comment: I like this one because it's more general than using nchar.

Comment: Actually, `nchar` with `substr` is more general solution - it's more/less a common practice in various languages. `gsub` is a nifty function that does all the dirty job in the background. Anyway, string manipulation in R is unthinkable without `gsub`. Me gusta.

Comment: But you have to know the length of the string, whereas in your solution, you don't. This is why I would argue why your solution is more general. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @aL3xa Thanks, but what I am precisely struggling with is the whole indexing inside a `lapply` call.  For example your procedure used as in @joran's answer works, but the following does not: `lapply(dats, function(x) assign(x$b,gsub("M$", "", x$b)))` nor `lapply(dats, function(x) assign(x[[1]][["b"]],gsub("M$", "", x[[1]][["b"]])))`.  Note I have tried the latter with all sorts of `[[` combinations...

Comment: @Roman, naah, everything's fine, it's just that regular expressions kick @$$... nothing more, nothing less... @Fred, I'm afraid that indexing thing "belongs" to a different question. =/

Comment: @aL3xa -1 I see your point but then your answer is only partial relative to the question posted, which is how to get from A to B as shown by @joran

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is another possibility, not neat, but intelligible:

```
for(i in seq(along=dats)) {
    c <- as.character(dats[[i]][["b"]])
    c <- substr(c, 1, nchar(c)-1)
    dats[[i]][["b"]] <- c
    dats
}
dats
```

I have to say that I find the whole `[[` versus `[` referencing very cryptic.

```
> str(dats[[i]][["b"]])
 chr [1:3] "325.049072" "325.049072" "325.049072"
> str(dats[[i]]["b"])
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ b: chr  "325.049072" "325.049072" "325.049072"
```

I proceed by trial and error.  Any pointers to a good explanation?

Comment: From the R docs: It is very important to distinguish Lst[[1]] from Lst[1]. ‘[[...]]’ is the operator used to select a single element, whereas ‘[...]’ is a general subscripting operator. Thus the former is the first object in the list Lst, and if it is a named list the name is not included. The latter is a sublist of the list Lst consisting of the first entry only. If it is a named list, the names are transferred to the sublist.

Comment: @Joran Thanks.  Part of the problem is that goggling "[" or "[[" is not very helpful.  If I may trouble you some more: Where in the R Docs did you find it?  Using what keywords?

Comment: Searching for help with R stuff can be a challenge, generally. That section I quoted is in the R manual (http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html) in the section on Lists, 6.1. The key is that `[[` returns a value and `[` returns a sublist (of a list).

Comment: Searching the built-in R help is a lot easier once you know that each of the operators have a help page.  Access this by embedding the operator in backticks or quotes, e.g. `?\`[\`` or `?"+"`